# Create query to capture the count of user logins per a given date range

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am working with SQL Server 2016. I am not sure if there is a built in report or method to do this or if I need to write a sql query.
I want to be able to generate a report (simple table is fine) to capture all the users who logged in (accessed) a certain database and the count of how many times they accessed it. I have very little SQL writing skills... table I am looking for to be generated would look something like below... the date range would be a variable I determine.. YYYY/MM/DD - YYYY/MM/DD or something similar

```
UserName | Count of Logins
---------------------------
user1    | 3
user2    | 5
user3    | 1
```

EDIT**

I am looking for the number of times a user authenticated to access database "x" (I will replace "x" will my dbid) for example if a user authed to the database at 8am and did nothing up until 2pm, and then preformed a query that counts as 1 "login" however if they login at 8am, then logout. and at 2pm again they log back in that counts as 2 "logins" and should reflect "2" in the counts field.

Comment: What *exactly* do you consider to be "accessed"? Users can authenticate to any database and then run a query against a different database that happens to reference a view that references a table in the database you're interested in. A user can authenticate to your database but never run any queries there. Or they can run 2 queries 10 minutes apart, is that 1 access or 2? So it is very important that you define (and understand the limitations of) exactly what you're trying to monitor. It's possible that SQL Server Audit is a solution, for example.

Comment: good question I did not clarify, I will update my question